# Auto compute form fields value in dynamic form with VueJS 2.5.17

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

I have a dynamic form with four input fields, I can add a new row or remove a row.

The first row is added when a pay button is clicked; when the pay button is clicked, the onGetModalAddRow() function runs and a modal is displayed with the initial form row containing 4 input fields with the subTotal & amountPaid fields predefined, allowing me to add a new row or remove a row.

The form fields for each row are:
subTotal:
amountPaid:
toBalance: 
paymentMethod:

What I want to achieve:

When the addRow button is clicked, I want it such that the amount toBalance in the previous row becomes the subTotal & amountPaid of the new row and so on to the zero amount toBalance.

The ability to disable the removeRow button in the previous row will also be an added feature: this will force the user to remove rows orderly so as to maintain accurate calculation.

But if there is a better way to allow users to remove any row (with the exemption of the first row) and still have an accurate computation of values for the form fields, then that will be highly appreciated.

CHECK THE CODE BELOW FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING:
HTML:

PAY BUTTON

```
<li><button type="button" v-on:click="onGetModalAddRow('splitpayments')" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#getPayFormModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap" title="Make Payment" >PAY</button></li>
```

PAYMENT DETAILS MODAL FORM

```
    <!-- /. START MODAL -->
    <!-- START SPLIT PAYMENT FORM INIT -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="getPayFormModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1">
                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                          <div class="modal-content">
                           <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1" >PAYMENT DETAILS</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                          </div>

         <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="vld-parent" ref="formContainer">

<input type="hidden" class="colorfieldblue" name="customer_amount_paid" id="customer_amount_paid" v-model="maincartsection.customer_amount_paid" :value="computeCustomerSubTotal" required />

<div v-for="(itm, index) in maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items" :id="index">
    <a v-on:click="removeRow(index)" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;" title="Remove Row" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Close"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> </a>

<div class="form-group" >

<div class="row">
<div :class="{'col-6':'col-6','error': errors.has('subtotal_' + itm.id)}" >

 <label :for="'subtotal'+itm.id" class="control-label">Sub Total:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control input"  :id="'subtotal'+index" :key="itm.id" :name="'subtotal_' + itm.id" v-validate="'required|min:3'" v-model="maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items[index].subtotal" :value="computeCustomerSubTotal" required  placeholder="0"  disabled="disabled" >

<div class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li v-text="errors.first('subtotal_' + itm.id)"></li></ul></div>

<div class="help-block" style="color: #dd4b39;" ><ul role="alert"><li ></li></ul></div>
 </div>

<div :class="{'col-6':'col-6','error': errors.has('amountpaid_' + itm.id)}" >

<label :for="'amountpaid'+itm.id" class="control-label">Amount Paid:</label>

 <input type="text" class="form-control input"  :id="'amountpaid'+index" :key="itm.id" :name="'amountpaid_' + itm.id" v-validate="'required'" v-model="maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items[index].amountpaid"  required placeholder="0.00" v-on:change="onAmountEntered(index)" @focus="onAmountPaidFieldFocus(index)" >

 <div class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li v-text="errors.first('amountpaid_' + itm.id)"></li></ul></div>

<div class="help-block" style="color: #dd4b39;" ><ul role="alert"><li ></li></ul></div>
</div>


</div>

</div>



<div class="form-group" >

<div class="row">

<div :class="{'col-6':'col-6','error': errors.has('tobalance_' + itm.id)}" >

<label :for="'tobalance'+itm.id" class="control-label">To Balance:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control input"  :id="'tobalance'+index" :key="itm.id" :name="'tobalance_' + itm.id" v-validate="'required'" v-model="maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items[index].tobalance" :value="computeToBalance" required  placeholder="0"  disabled="disabled" >


<div class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li v-text="errors.first('tobalance_' + itm.id)"></li></ul></div>

<div class="help-block" style="color: #dd4b39;" ><ul role="alert"><li ></li></ul></div>
</div>


 <div :class="{'col-6':'col-6','error': errors.has('paymentmethod_' + itm.id)}" >

 <label :for="'paymentmethod'+itm.id" class="control-label">Payment Method:</label>

<select class="custom-select col-12 input" :id="'paymentmethod'+index" :key="itm.id" :name="'paymentmethod_' + itm.id" v-validate="'required'" v-model="maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items[index].paymentmethod" required>

<option v-for="(paymntoptn, index) in items.availablepaymentoptions" :value="paymntoptn.payment_title_slug" v-text="paymntoptn.payment_title"></option>

 </select>


<div class="help-block"><ul role="alert"><li v-text="errors.first('paymentmethod_' + itm.id)"></li></ul></div>

<div class="help-block" style="color: #dd4b39;" ><ul role="alert"><li ></li></ul></div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>


<hr style="background-color: #009efb;" />

</div>

</form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" style="margin-right: 30%;" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect text-left" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>

<button type="button" v-on:click="addRow()" title="Split Payment" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" style="float: right; margin-right: 3%;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button> 

<button type="button" :disabled="errors.any()"  class="btn btn-success">PAY NOW</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END SPLIT PAYMENT FORM INIT -->
                                <!-- /. END MODAL -->
```

JAVASCRIPT (VueJs):

```
//Start Modal

    onGetModalAddRow: function (modalformdatasection) {
        self = this;
        //Empty previous modalformdata array, then Add new rows for current form data
        self.validations.fieldstatuslogs = [];
        self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items = [];
        self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.id = 0;


        //Start splitpayments
        if (modalformdatasection == "splitpayments") {

            self._addRowHelper(self.computeCustomerSubTotal, self.computeCustomerSubTotal, self.computeToBalance, '');

        }
        //End splitpayments

    },
    //End Modal

    //Start addRow Helper Function
    _addRowHelper: function(newSubTotal, amountpaid, tobalance,  paymentmethod){

        //START ADD ANOTHER ROW
        self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.push({ id: self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.id++, subtotal: newSubTotal, amountpaid: amountpaid, tobalance: tobalance, paymentmethod: paymentmethod });

        self.validations.fieldstatuslogs.push({
            subtotal: {
                is_valid: true,
                text: ''
            },
            amountpaid: {
                is_valid: true,
                text: ''
            },
            tobalance: {
                is_valid: true,
                text: ''
            },

            paymentmethod: {
                is_valid: true,
                text: ''
            },
        });
        //END ADD ANOTHER ROW

    },
    //End addRow Helper Function




                //START SPLIT PAYMENT - addRow Function
    addRow: function(){

    self = this;
    var lastiteminarrayIndex = '';

    if(self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.length < 1){
     // alert('First Item Added');
     //Disable Amount Paid Feild
        //document.getElementById('customer_amount_paid').focus();

     //self.splitPaymentClicked = true;
     self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.splitPaymentStatus = 1;
      //Initialize First Item Value with Cart Value

    //Call onGetModalAddRow Function to Initialize First Item Value with Cart Value
    self.onGetModalAddRow('splitpayments');

      return;
    }

    lastiteminarrayIndex = self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.length-1;
    var subTotalOfIndex = parseFloat(document.getElementById('subtotal'+lastiteminarrayIndex).value);

    if(!parseFloat(document.getElementById('amountpaid'+lastiteminarrayIndex).value )){
      alert('Amount Paid must be a Number and Can not be less than 1');
      return;
     }

    var amountPaidOfIndex = parseFloat(document.getElementById('amountpaid'+lastiteminarrayIndex).value);



    var newSubTotal = subTotalOfIndex - amountPaidOfIndex;

    //set value of tobalance in lastindex
    document.getElementById('tobalance'+lastiteminarrayIndex).value = newSubTotal;

    if(newSubTotal < 1){
      if(confirm('There is No Outstanding Balance, Do you still want to proceed to add a new row? ')){

        //START ADD ANOTHER ROW
        self._addRowHelper(newSubTotal,'','','');
        //END ADD ANOTHER ROW
        return;

      }else{          
        return;
      }
    }

    //START ADD ANOTHER ROW
    self._addRowHelper(newSubTotal,'','','');
    //END ADD ANOTHER ROW
    return;

  },


removeRow: function(idx){

    self = this;
    if(self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.length < 1){
      alert('List is Empty');
      return;
    }

    lastiteminarrayIndex = self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.length-1;

      //REMOVE OTHER ITEMS BELOW TOP ITEM
      if(lastiteminarrayIndex == idx){
        self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.splice(idx, 1); 

        if(self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items.length < 1){
          //self.splitPaymentClicked = false;
         // self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.splitPaymentStatus = 0;
         // document.getElementById('customer_amount_paid').focus();  
           return;
         }


      }else{
        self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.items = [];
       // self.splitPaymentClicked = false;
       // self.maincartsection.splitpaymentformitems.splitPaymentStatus = 0;
       // document.getElementById('customer_amount_paid').focus();
      }
      return;
      //END REMOVE OTHER ITEMS BELOW TOP ITEM

  },
```